# Initializing Object with Arrays VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, oop

I'm trying to create a class with arrays in it, and I'm having issues creating the class for it...

**CLASS:**

```
Private pST(0 To 2) As String

Public Property Get ST() As String
   ST() = pST()
End Property
Public Property Let ST(value() As String)  '<---- ERROR HERE
   pST() = value()
End Property
```

**CODE RUN:**

```
Sub test()

   Dim foo As cPurchaseOrder
   Set foo = New cPurchaseOrder

   foo.ST(0) = "test"

   Debug.Print foo.ST(0)

End Sub
```

**THE ERROR:**

> Compile error:
>
> Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid Set final parameter.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I properly initialize a class with arrays as variables?

**EDIT:** *in relation to Mat's Mug response*

**CLASS CHANGED:**

```
Private pST As Variant

Public Property Get STContent(ByVal index As Long) As String
    STContent = pST(index)
End Property

Public Property Let STContent(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As String)
    pST(index) = value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   ReDim pST(0 To 2)
End Sub
```

**CODE RUN TO TEST:**

```
Sub test()

   Dim foo As cPurchaseOrder
   Set foo = New cPurchaseOrder

   foo.STContent(0) = "test" '<--- Type mismatch here

   Debug.Print foo.STContent(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to initialize the array in the `Class_Initialize` handler, e.g. `ReDim pST(0 To 20)`, before you start assigning to it. If the backing field was a compile-time array, the error would have been "index out of bounds"

Comment: @Mat'sMug I've added the `Class_Initialize` and it works fine when I just assign a value to `foo.STContent(0)`. However when I try to output the value, I'm not getting `Variable not defined` on `Content = pST(index) in the `Public Property Get STContent`

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a nascence, I'm still quite new to `Class` objects and learning :(

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and avoid copy-pasting code from random strangers on the Internet ;-)  the assignment would be `STContent = pST(index)`.

Comment: Oh there we go... not sure how I missed that sorry!

Comment: Works perfect now! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your getter would need to return a `String()` array for the types to be consistent:

```
Public Property Get ST() As String()
```

However I wouldn't recommend exposing an array like this. First because assigning typed arrays is rather painful, second because the setter (`Property Let`) is actually cheating here:

```
Public Property Let ST([ByRef] value() As String)
```

Unless you specify `ByVal` explicitly, a parameter is always passed `ByRef` in VBA... except there's this quirk about `Property Let` - the RHS/value parameter is always passed `ByVal` at run-time.

And arrays can only ever be passed `ByRef`.

Therefore, a property that gets (or assigns, actually) a whole array doesn't make much sense.

A better way would be to *encapsulate* the array (I'd make it a `Variant` though), and expose its contents (not the array itself) through an *indexed property*:

```
Private internal As Variant 'String array

'...

Public Property Get Content(ByVal index As Long) As String
    Content = internal(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Content(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As String)
    internal(index) = value
End Property
```

Comment: I really like they way you approach this and the explanation is superb! I ran into another issue with this method however. I ran the code `foo.Content(0) = "test"` and I'm receiving the error "*Type mismatch*"

Comment: Is there anything wrong with "cheating" the setter in your explanation here?

Comment: Not sure about that type mismatch issue, could be related to your backing field, did you make it a variant? Is it initialized? As for "cheating", IMO exposing an array setter is just asking for problems.. not to mention it defeats the purpose of a class/object, which is to *encapsulate* data.

Comment: I've edited my question to relate to your answer and my new question in comments above

Comment: @Maldred unless you didn't show it, you're not initializing the array, it's just a `Variant/Empty` until you do that.

Comment: You can do that in the `Class_Initialize` handler

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of issues there.

First, your Property Get needs to return a String array. Second, your array needs to be dynamic, or you need to rewrite the whole thing so that you pass an index value to it, otherwise there is no way to indicate which value you are passing to the array. So, for example, using a dynamic array:

```
Private pST() As String

Public Property Get ST() As String()
   ST = pST
End Property
Public Property Let ST(value() As String)
   pST() = value()
End Property
```

and the calling code:

```
Sub test()

   Dim foo As cPurchaseOrder
   Set foo = New cPurchaseOrder
   Dim asData() As String
   ReDim asData(0)
   asData(0) = "test"

   foo.ST = asData

   Debug.Print foo.ST()(0)

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't be sure form the original what the intent was.

Answer (score 0):

It is getting late here but give it a try. In the module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

   Dim foo As cPurchaseOrder
   Set foo = New cPurchaseOrder
   foo.AddValueToSt "test", 1
   Debug.Print foo.ST(1)

End Sub
```

In the Class:

```
Option Explicit

Private pST

Public Property Get ST() As Variant
   ST = pST
End Property

Public Property Let ST(value As Variant)
   pST = value
End Property

Public Function AddValueToSt(value As Variant, position As Long)
    pST(position) = value
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim pST(2)
End Sub
```

This is my way to use the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). When I say "my way", for me this pattern is translated to "Whenever some OOP requires more than 5 minutes of thinking simply add a function."